# TypeScript KeyOf with Type Constraint for optional nested property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function that takes multiple generic parameters:

```js
function myFunction<
  L extends Q[K]["nodes"],
  Q extends Record<K, { nodes: L[] }>,
  K extends keyof Q>(
    document: Q,
    dataKey: K
  ): L[] {
  //do something with the Document to a result of type QueryResult (not relevant)
  let result: Q = {} as any;
  //now I want to get the nodes attribute type-safe
  let extracted = result[dataKey]?.["nodes"] ?? []; // should be of type ListItemType

  return extracted;
}
```

`Q` should always contain a key `K` with the type of `Q[K]` (lets call it `Data`) having at least the following attributes :

```js
type Data = {
  nodes?: L[]
}
```

however, `nodes` as well as `Q[K]` are optional.

`Q` is always the  subset of a specific type, but there are too many fields with a nested `nodes` field, all with different types to list all the possibilities by hand.

Which constraints do I need to add to my Generics so it is ensured that `Q[K]` has the `nodes` attribute, and so the type of `L[]` is inferred to a required `type Q[K]["nodes"]`?

##### Example:

```js
interface Contained {
  key?: {
    nodes?: number[]
  }
}

let a : Contained = {} as any

myFunction(a, "key")
```

In this example, I want `L` to be `number`. Please keep in mind that I cannot change the definition of contained. The error is:

```
Argument of type 'Contained' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"key", { nodes: unknown[]; }>'.
  Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
    Type '{ nodes: number[]; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ nodes: unknown[]; }'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ nodes: unknown[]; }'.
```

How can I achieve this without removing any generics and without changing the definition of contained?

See this playground:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAPAKEUQBlEBTADyjLABMBnRARQG0BpAXRYCIw5ay9bhwA0hZuSo0GiAEpkIcAE61cbEYgDeiPgPoAuEiw6IAvgD4xRNpOp1GAazKo4wZuYAU4orTgQQyDRQhkxWRIi0AIZQkWzOhmziAJSGxMZa4gD0mb6I9HCBUAAWMGAA5ogA7jDFiMVkiAAifgFBdXCIkYhKgiAANlCIrnWoAA4NTCBkSqjy9P2DHnyDPX1kAG6RYFBJ4msrvQMhiAC8WqadjFuoANxZmXyViACSVVuDUB1lZB9FDbqCTpQKBKGAAIxA1BG4wAtPRIsAyHsfrYlJFoGRaKduocoCwojE4qgOAB%20AB0PABQhMJJJiGMN0Q2TyRTg-SxYIawygYwaxBg9Cgz2oyAAKrz8OIelAQEokJQQejqLQ7qZJaVqEpgOiGgBhBAxUqYjJEJyoEmGTTeHT8QSGMABTlKYziNVq-D7TqIQz67aRI1Ys6aC6RK5gVCStCYSCwBAeSIabhm7i7fBAA)

Comment: Could you [edit] to provide a [mre]?  If I put the code here into my IDE I get a lot of errors around undeclared types and values; could you make sure you remove any third party dependencies from the code (or tag your question as needing them) and any undeclared things (or define them)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I messed up editing the post on StackOverflow. The example contains no external imports now.

Comment: I still see problems with `AnyConnection`, whatever that is.

Comment: Was meant to be AnyNodeContainer<T>.

Comment: So far I have [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ1KDN) and I don't see any problem.  In your question you say "`SelectableType` was inferred as `unkown`" but I don't know what `SelectableType` is, and I can guess what `unkown` is but it seems like maybe you haven't passed this through an IDE or proofread it enough?  I think I'll probably come back one more time and then move on; could you [edit] the code to be a [mre] where the problem you're having is clearly demonstrated? If something is improperly inferred or there's an error, the code should show it.

Comment: Sorry causing the confusion. I really appreciate the help and effort! I updated the description and linked a typescript playground. If you hover the function, you can see that L is inferred as unknown. It is essential that `L` has the correct type, as the real function return is much more complex and relies on `L` having the correct inferred type (in this case `number`)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdEbMm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the patience. Due to your working examples I figured out that the `key` I was accessing is optional, which I somehow didn't notice before. So you weren't missing anything. [This is the problem case](https://tsplay.dev/N75drW). Sorry for misleading you, If you want you can just type down your answer because it answers my inaccurate question, sorry again.

Comment: Hmm, maybe?  Or you could delete or re-edit your question to be the correct thing (although I'm not sure I want to spend much more time here )

Comment: Okay, I refactored the question. After trying even more, I dont think this is possible, but I've already learned a lot about TS generics today so that's a plus. Curious to see if you can correct me.

Comment: Like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w84dMw) maybe?

Comment: Okay I'll write up an an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inference to work as desired, you generally want a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function to have the minimum number of type parameters that can describe your operation, and ideally you want each such type parameter to appear as directly as possible in the types of your function parameters.

In your examples, the `Q` and `K` type parameters appear directly as the types of the `document` and `dataKey` parameters, and are therefore easy for the compiler to infer.  On the other hand, the `L` type parameter doesn't appear *at all* in the types of the function parameters; it is only related to them through a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `Q`, and constraints are not used as inference sites.  That means it is almost impossible for the compiler to infer `L` and it will tend to fall back to `unknown`.  We don't need to include `L` as a type parameter; instead we can *compute* the type represented by `L` from `Q` and `K`.

That is, we could replace `L` with something like `Q[K]['nodes']` and it would work:

```
declare function myFunction<
  Q extends Record<K, { nodes: any[] }>,
  K extends keyof Q>(
    document: Q,
    dataKey: K
  ): Q[K]["nodes"]>;
```

---

Well, it would work *if* `nodes` and `K` weren't both optional properties.  But they *are* optional properties, so you can't just [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a possibly `undefined` object type without the compiler complaining.  We want to compute something like `MaybeIndex<T, P>` that evaluates to the type that `T[P]` would be if `T` is not undefined.  To do so, we could use [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) which removes both `null` and `undefined` from a union, and then index into that.

So the call signature needs to change to something like:

```
declare function myFunction<
  Q extends Partial<Record<K, { nodes?: any[] }>>,
  K extends keyof Q>(
    document: Q,
    dataKey: K
  ): NonNullable<NonNullable<Q[K]>["nodes"]>;
```

where we are applying `NonNullable` to every possibly-`undefined` type before continuing.  This now works from the caller's side:

```
interface Contained {
  key?: {
    nodes?: number[]
  }
}
declare let a: Contained;
const ret = myFunction(a, "key");
// const ret: number[]
```

As for the implementation side, the following doesn't produce errors,

```
function myFunction<
  Q extends Partial<Record<K, { nodes?: any[] }>>,
  K extends keyof Q>(
    document: Q,
    dataKey: K
  ): NonNullable<NonNullable<Q[K]>["nodes"]> {
  let result: Q = {} as any;
  let extracted = result[dataKey]?.["nodes"] ?? []; // any[]
  return extracted;
}
```

but that's just because `extracted` is inferred as `any[]` by having `Q` fall back to its constraint.  And [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is intentionally loose about types.  The compiler is happy to let you assign `any[]` to `NonNullable<NonNullable<Q[K]>["nodes"]>`, but it can't really *verify* that this is correct.  So you should be careful to double-check your implementation to make sure that you're not lying about what you're returning.  (Indeed it is possible for this to be wrong if `Q`'s nested property is some more specific array type like a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[1, 2, 3]`, in which case `myFunction()` claims to return `[1, 2, 3]` even though it's possibly an empty array.  I doubt this is going to be an issue, so I won't digress here about how to make the types anticipate it, but the point is that you need to test thoroughly against use cases to make sure that it works for the range of anticipated inputs.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAPAWAChFEBFRAUwA8oKwATAZ0QAUBDAJ1jYBtcAlChDgd6uANIAaRAG9EYOPQqMA-AC5EbMKgDaAXUQBfAHzHJREuMo06TRAGsKqOMDLGAFBZKJ6cCCGQ6KA1Sc2JvejYoNnEnDXEvAEoNADkEFJAeHjYAIx4KXDSwDKzc-NxSHXE9Yx0AIgUlRjqa2S98qEQOZUzgskQAXllDTWYtVABudopO6igONmgKekGunp4oHUjo2NQ9FQA6esblFsQVFUR9CcQAelvNbX0vbqgQDiQ5haX6KcJDIhEGBgWgcYCLCiIADCCGiwOWbXCjlQ6kR3nkimUqLAARyFA4z3CAP+gMIHU0GhhILY8JWQxkIzYY20pOEYEYnVeqzQmEgsAQ7jY0jqyLqiT+90QbI5az6OOQeIJelJQA)